# Auto-generated code in WPF shows error. (C#, WPF, Visual Studio Community 2013)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, visual-studio-2013, dataset

Recently i have started playing with C# in Visual Studio 2013 Community. I was creating a simple data binding while i encountered following error. What i was doing i was using drag-n-drop fr om my database to main window. Visual studio generated required XAML and .cs file. There was following error present with the code. I searched a lot and didn't found a solution. It was showing on

Error: "an object reference is required to access non-static field method or property"

following is my XAML.

```
 <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:rrplproj" x:Class="rrplproj.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1024" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:rDataSet x:Key="rDataSet"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="dateViewSource" Source="{Binding Date, Source={StaticResource rDataSet}}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="deliveryViewSource" Source="{Binding Delivery, 
Source={StaticResource rDataSet}}"/>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Background="#FFDBFDF8">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="165*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="172*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="171*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="56*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="149*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="18*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="grid1" DataContext="{StaticResource dateViewSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="19,23,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="151">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Date:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" 
VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <DatePicker x:Name="dateDatePicker" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" 
SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" 
VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="grid2" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{StaticResource deliveryViewSource}" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="64,18,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Truck No:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" 
VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="truckNoTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" 
Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding TruckNo, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

and following is auto generated code by ide in C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace rrplproj
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // Load data into the table Date. You can modify this code as needed.
            rrplproj.rDataSetTableAdapters.DateTableAdapter rDataSetDateTableAdapter = 
        new rrplproj.rDataSetTableAdapters.DateTableAdapter();
            rDataSetDateTableAdapter.Fill(rDataSet.Date);
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource dateViewSource = 
            ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("dateViewSource")));
            dateViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
            // Load data into the table Delivery. You can modify this code as needed.
            rrplproj.rDataSetTableAdapters.DeliveryTableAdapter rDataSetDeliveryTableAdapter = 
            new rrplproj.rDataSetTableAdapters.DeliveryTableAdapter();
            rDataSetDeliveryTableAdapter.Fill(rDataSet.Delivery);
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource deliveryViewSource = 
            ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("deliveryViewSource")));
            deliveryViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        }
    }
}
```

The error is shown here

```
rDataSetDateTableAdapter.Fill(rDataSet.Date);
```

and here:

```
rDataSetDeliveryTableAdapter.Fill(rDataSet.Delivery);
```

it is showing red line under

```
(rDataSet.Date)
```

and

```
(rDataSet.Delivery)
```

Your help is appreciated.

Thank you for reading till the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never tried it with data set, but it simple means that it can not create an instance of rDataSet which is in this namespace - rrplproj we would need a little info abt rDataSet in order to understand it further .. also read about creating dataset instances in xaml..

or else in the constructor of your code behind write this ...

```
myObj = new rDataSet();
this.Resources.Add("rDataSet", myObj);
```

and remove this from your xaml

```
<local:rDataSet x:Key="rDataSet"/>
```

this would add a resource to rDataSet